# Using NodeJS modules in Ionic 5 Angular 12 Application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, mobile

I am using a NodeJS package in an Ionic 5 app. With the upgrade to Angular 12, the NodeJS package is breaking due to webpack update to v5.

I have tried to follow the error prompts and other questions answered and they all mention editing the webpack config file. I am new to Ionic and I don't see this file in my project. Is there an equivalent in Ionic, or can I not use this package anymore?

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Inonic 5 only with angular 11.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @angular-builders/custom-webpack package, and then edit webpack.config.js by following the instructions given by the error